# How to install a free theme on Magento 2.2.5 on XAMPP local host

Tags: theme, magento-2.2.5, localhost, theme-overriding

I have installed the latest version of **Magento2.2.5** without sample data using XAMPP. Now I am trying to install a free third party **theme** from **Venus** **themes**.

- I have copied the `app` folder from the free theme folder and pasted it into root folder of my **Megento2.2.5**.
- Then I tried to run the shell command for `upgrade`.

But still I am not able to find & select the theme from the admin panel of **Magento**.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento everything works first with the registration & the declaration so first check that your theme contains the `registration.php` & `theme.xml` file at the below location

> magento_root/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme

Now just run the below command for registering & installing the setups for your theme into your magento.

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Now go to the admin panel after login go to the below location from the left navigation menu

> content > design > configuration > store/website

Select the store & then select your theme from the drop-down that you have just installed & save it & run the below commands now for the data deployment.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile (you can avoid this)
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now you can refresh the front-end for testing the theme

> Note: At the time of development change your magento mode into the
>   developer mode with the below command
>
> ```
> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the theme copied to the correct place.

```
<Magento root dir>/app/design/frontend/YourTheme
```

If theme copy correctly as per given path, Run below command and check again.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

- Open downloaded folder and copy all from app folder.
- Open your Magento 2.2.5 root folder and go to app folder.
- Create folder "Design" under app folder(ex.app/design/frontend/Your_Theme).
- Paste all downloaded code.

Then Run all commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```